# why is react devtools not connecting to my application when i open it on safari?

Tags: reactjs, safari, react-devtools

I am trying to debug apple pay and so I need to use react devtools on my safari browser.
I installed the npm package react-devtools and added the script to my index.html page as they instructed but I am unable to get the react-devtools instance to connect to my safari app, however as soon as I turn the app on chrome it will connect, and show the proper components. I am not sure what I am missing as all other questions I've seen on google and documentation on the react page seems to imply that it should automatically be connected after adding the script and loading the application on the desired browser.

Comment: In order to get a better answer, it would be better to post code and commands of the your problem. Also, try to be more specific of your actions in order to understand the problem.